# Writing a generator function in php generating no elements

Tags: php, generator

I can write a generator returning a single element:

```
function MyGen() {
   yield 1;
}
```

In a derived class I want to write a generator that never returns any element:

```
function MyGen() {

}
```

An empty function is not a generator and will fail if passed as a`foreach` argument.
So - How can I write a generator which will always return no elements?

Comment: What would be the point of generating nothing.

Comment: @RiggsFolly It can be if required data is absent

Comment: `yield;` returns a `NULL` element.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work (php7)

```
function MyGen() {
    yield from [];
}
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php

Comment: Of course, it works, it works with every value, but I don't think it's exactly what the requester was expecting.